# Tkinter event for detecting new USB device, or device removal

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter to write an application to interface with USB devices in python, and I would like to show my user a list of devices that are connected. I do not see USB device addition/removal as a supported event in tkinter- does anyone know how I could write my own platform independent class to do this?

Comment: most likely tkinter would not handle this. It's a gui library. What you would use is a usb library (or get down and dirty and write that functionality yourself). You would update your tkinter gui when the other library tells you the usb interface(s) had changed. [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453256/tkinter-and-detection-of-usb-devices).

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter will not handle the detection, although of course you can use tkinter to notify the user of the event.

You can try [PyUSB](https://walac.github.io/pyusb/) for a cross-platform approach. Or you can try to roll your own.

On Windows you would need to use PyWin32 to call the Windows API ([Registering for Device Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363432(VS.85).aspx)).

Linux would be [pyudev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508236/how-can-i-run-code-whenever-a-usb-device-is-unplugged-without-requiring-root) in most cases, although there are alternative methods (e.g. putting on watch on where gvfs will mount the drive).